# Difference between Numeric, Combinatorial, and Geometric Computing

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry

In the paper [1], author has discussed a distinction between the 3 types of computations: numeric, combinatorial, and geometric. The author says that Geometric computation is one that has elements of both combinatorial and numeric computation. That is:

> Geometric Computing = Numerical + Combinatorial Computing.
>
> Numerical computing is exemplified by the problem of solving linear
> systems of equations; graph searching is a typical problem of
> combinatorial computing. The convex hull problem for a set of points
> is a canonical example of geometric computing: the points are
> specified by numbers but the convex hull is essentially a
> combinatorial structure (a labeled graph). Linear programming counts
> as geometric computing but solving linear systems does not qualify.

I am confused about the last sentence: "**Linear Programming counts as geometric computing but solving linear systems does not qualify.**" Why is that so? We have a perfectly geometric representation of solving linear systems (through intersection of lines and planes). Why is Linear Programming geometric then?

**So, my first question is: Why is LP geometric while solving linear systems is not?**

Now, in book chapter [2], the author further clarifies:

> The mere presence of combinatorial structures in a numerical
> computation does not make a computation “geometric.” There must be
> some nontrivial consistency condition holding between the numerical
> data and the combinatorial data. Thus, we would not consider the
> classical shortest-path problems on graphs to be geometric: the
> numerical weights assigned to edges of the graphs are not restricted
> by any consistency condition. Note that common restrictions on the
> weights (positivity, integrality, etc.) are not consistency
> restrictions. But the related Euclidean shortest-path problem (Chapter
> 31) is geometric.

So, this "consistency condition" seems to be the key distinction to determining if a problem is geometric or not. Could someone shed more light on these consistency conditions?

**So, my second question is: What are these consistency conditions that makes a problem geometric?**

#### References:

- [1] Yap, Chee-Keng. “Towards Exact Geometric Computation".” Computational Geometry, 1997, 21.
- [2] Sharma, Vikram, and Chee K Yap. “Chapter-45 ROBUST GEOMETRIC COMPUTATION,” Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry. Third edition. Boca Raton: CRC Press, 2017.

Comment: You might find the paper [Classroom Examples of Robustness Problems in Geometric Computations](https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/ftp/classroomExamplesNonrobustness.pdf) to be worth a read. They do a nice job illustrating why geometric problems in particular are so difficult.

Comment: Thank you @DanielShapero This looks like an accessible paper, aimed at clarifying pretty much my doubt! I will read it.

Comment: As for question 1: I think you're overthinking this. The author you quote is providing their personal perspective of which box they would put different problems in, but there is certainly a large degree of subjectivity to that. It's not worth trying to spend too much time on such questions.